# Get net bios name with DirectoryEntry

Tags: c#, ssl, dns, ldap, directoryentry

I need to retrieve the following items using the DirectoryEntry (strictly) in C#:

- Default Domain
- All domains in forests
- All domains in trusts
- All groups that a user/group is a member of
- All group/user that is a member of a group

Previously these were done using the Forest Class/GroupPrincipal/UserPrincipal but these do not fully support SSL.

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

K

Comment: WindowsIdentity currentUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
List<string> groups = currentUser.Groups.Select(ident =>
(ident.Translate(typeof (NTAccount)) as NTAccount).Value).ToList();

that would get you a list of all groups the current user is a member of. I know Its not trough a directoryEntry but who know's it might be useful to you anyway.

Comment: Thanks but it is not. I am using a remote AD with SSL